# SQL Natural Join and use clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, natural-join

so i have 2 tables with the following data

```
*where a star is a primary key.
*and a # is a unique key.
```

**Table 1**

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════════╗
║ #nlm ║ data2 ║ *data3 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════════╝
```

**Table 2**

```
╔══════╦═════╗
║ *pid ║ nlm ║
╚══════╩═════╝
```

The goal is to get data2 when I know pid. I've tried this, and failed badly.

```
 SELECT data2 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING nlm WHERE pid = 3;
```

Comment: Are you getting error messages or just unexpected results?

Comment: error message about my syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural join connects two tables using common column names, and it uses the `using` clause.  Other joins use the `on` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT table1.data2
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 
     on table1.nlm = table2.`#nlm`
WHERE table2.pid = 3;
```

Comment: `#` isn't part of the column name, it's just his way of marking a unique key in the schema description. Although the types of keys are totally irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `USING` clause requires that the column names be in parentheses:

```
SELECT data2 FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 USING (nlm)
WHERE pid = 3
```

This should also be an INNER JOIN, since the `WHERE` clause requires that it find a row in `table2`.